# Form Select with Multiple Options (Show another Input when "Others" and any other option selected)

Tags: jquery, forms

I have form where one of the selectors is multiple. One of the options of this selector is "Other", once this is selected extra input shows up to give an option to enter additional information.

Since this is a multiple choice there might be a scenario that user will choose one or more of the options + "other". So the way it is done so far, there is no possibility to choose both, and having extra input to stay ready for use, and this is what I'm after. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Already working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/192yb7ut/11/

HTML:

```
   <div id="other_income_selector">
        <label for="other_income">SELECT</label>
        <select 
        class="form-control other_income" name="other_income" id="other_income" multiple>
            <option value="None">None</option>
            <option value="Employment (PAYE)">Employment (PAYE)</option>
            <option value="Dividends">Dividends</option>
            <option value="Pension Income">Pension Income</option>
            <option value="Property (Rental) Income">Property (Rental) Income</option>
            <option value="Foreign Income">Foreign Income</option>
            <option value="Capital Gains">Capital Gains</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
         </select>
    </div>
    
    <div id="other_income_other_input" style="display: none;">
        <label for="other_income_other">OTHER</label>
        <input type="text" 
        class="form-control other_income_other" name="other_income_other" id="other_income_other">
    </div> 

My JS:

    $(document).on('change', '#other_income', function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();
        el = $("#other_income_other_input");
        other_income = this.value;
        if (other_income == "Other") {
            el.show();

        }
        else {
            el.hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the state of the option is selected and display the other form based on that:

```
$("#other_income").on("change", function()
{
    if($(this).find("[value=\"Other\"]").is(":selected") == true)
    $("#other_income_other_input").show();
  else
    $("#other_income_other_input").hide();
});
```

Comment: @Nita Your JS fiddle is same as this code - What magically he has changed simple and plain ? Your JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/192yb7ut/11/

Comment: its a different code mate: if($(this).find("[value=\"Other\"]").is(":selected") == true) <- this make a difference, i guess @John just send the same link by mistake,

Comment: @Nita You are probably a beginner i would suppose. You NEED to consider the IDEA behind the code. What i am saying is that your JS fiddle is producing the SAME results as his John's code producing. I hope you get my point here. Writing the code different way does not MAKE a difference here and adding more functions like `.find` to get the SAME results does NOT make a code simple and clean. Thanks

Comment: @AlwaysHelping its not the same functionality. My version works with multiple select while his original code only works with single select.